# How to format `dd` speed units?

Tags: dd

`dd` scales its reported speed (e.g. `MB/s` or `kB/s`), but I would like to enforce that it always use the same unit, e.g. `B/s`.  How can I enforce that `dd` always prints the same units?

Example usage:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/testfile bs=100k count=1k && sync
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
104857600 bytes transferred in 0.165040 secs (635346520 bytes/sec)
```

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: I don't think this is possible given the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dd.1posix.html)